# Finding the value of limit $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a+3h)}{2h}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Given that $f^{\prime}(a)=5$ (the function can be defined for $x=a$),
find

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a+3h)}{2h} =?$$

I have tried using these two formulas that define the derivatives:

1) $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a-h)}{2h} =5$

2) $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h} =5$

but, seemingly I can't achieve an implicit algebric expression that will help me solve the problem... I'mm really stumped and can't seem to figure out, how to even approach it? (Btw I have not an answer...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gimusi's (formal) approach may well be preferable to my *informal* approach, which may be the perspective that the questioner *intended*.

Anyway, $f'(a) = 5 \;$ implies that as $\;h \rightarrow 0, \;f(a + kh) \rightarrow f(a) + 5kh.$

Therefore, $\dfrac{f(a+h) - f(a+3h)}{2h} \rightarrow \dfrac{5h - 15h}{2h} = -5.$

Comment: This way is not completely correct, in particular $$\;h \rightarrow 0, \;f(a + kh) \rightarrow f(a) + 5kh$$ is meaningless since h appears on the RHS of the limit. You should improve that.

Comment: @gimusi "this way is not completely correct..."  Of course not, hence my emphasis on the *informality* of my approach.  The point of my *answer* was not a mathematical demonstration but an **intuition stretching exercise** for the OP.  For example, the OP might begin to consider the *similarity* between $f(x)$ and $g(x)=5x,$ in a **neighborhood** of $a.$

Comment: The informal approach can lead to big misunderstanding of the subject. The statement $$f(a + kh) \rightarrow f(a) + 5kh$$ is really bad also for informal way, maybe it should be better $$f(a + kh) \sim f(a) + 5kh$$ In any case any informal approch should be followed by a formal and correct explanation by you or by the asker himself, otherwise it is completely useless and maybe dangerous.

Comment: @gimusi Also, it is important to consider the skill level of the OP as well as the *intent* of the questioner.  The question asked for the **computation of an answer** rather than a **mathematical demonstration**.  **Why?**

Comment: @gimusi I think we should agree to disagree.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a+3h)}{2h}=\frac12\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-\frac32\frac{f(a+3h)-f(a)}{3h}$$

then by definition of derivative

$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a+3h)}{2h}=\frac12\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-\frac32\lim_{3h\to 0}\frac{f(a+3h)-f(a)}{3h}=\\=\frac 125-\frac325=-5$$

or as an alternative by the equivalent definition of differential

$$f(a+h)=f(a)+f'(a)\cdot h+o(h)$$

then

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a+3h)}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(a)+f'(a)\cdot h-f(a)-f'(a)\cdot3h+o(h)}{2h}=\\=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{-f'(a)\cdot2h+o(h)}{2h}=\lim_{h\to0} \frac{-f'(a)\cdot2+o(1)}{2}=-5$$

Comment: I am new to the subjec..  can't figure out how it would help me to solve nor how did you get that equation

Comment: @user6394019 The equation is a simple equality aimed to use the definition of limit.

Comment: @user6394019 I've added some more detail.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $f$ is differentiable at $a$, you can write
$$
f(a+h)=f(a)+hf'(a)+h\varphi(h)
$$
where $\lim_{h\to0}\varphi(h)=0$; just set
$$
\varphi(h)=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}-f'(a)
$$
and apply differentiability. Therefore
$$
\frac{f(a+h)-f(a+3h)}{2h}=
\frac{f(a)+hf'(a)+h\varphi(h)-f(a)-3hf'(a)-3h\varphi(3h)}{2h}
$$
and, simplifying, you get
$$
-f'(a)+\frac{1}{2}\varphi(h)-\frac{3}{2}\varphi(3h)
$$
so
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a+3h)}{2h}=
\lim_{h\to0}\bigl(-f'(a)+\tfrac{1}{2}\varphi(h)-\tfrac{3}{2}\varphi(3h)\bigr)=-f'(a)
$$

Comment: Note that this produces @gimusi's coefficients without guesswork.

Comment: +1 especially for the remark made in comments section.